# перенос абсолютных значений в область нормированных значений и обратно

Tags: нейронные-сети, r, нормализация-данных

Я учусь делать регрессию нейросетями и столкнулся с такой проблемой 
есть выборка `х1`   *#это просто фрагмент, одна строка из матрицы (только для примера)*

```
x1 <- c(100,300,150)
```

есть целевое значение которое надо предсказать `у1`

```
y1 <- 450
```

`у1` это просто продолжение ряда `х1`

для наглядности нарисую

```
plot( c(x1,y1)  , t="b" ,col= 4,lwd=3)
lines(x1,col=2,t="b",lwd=3)
text(2,350,labels = "x1...values" , col=2,font = 2)
text(3,350,labels = "y1" , col=4,font = 2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для сети данные нужно нормализовать к примеру в диапазон с ноля по 1.
Сделаем это функцией `normalize`

```
normalize <- function(x)   return((x- min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x)))
```

получаем нормализированую `х1`, назовем ее `х2`

```
x2 <- normalize(x1)
```

**Вопрос** как мне теперь получить нормализированое целевое значение от `у1` ? чтобы сеть смогла нормально обучаться 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И сразу следующий связный **вопрос**: Когда я от сети получу нормализированый ответ `у2(нормализ. у1)` , как мне его потом обратно преобразовать в ответ в абсолютных значениях ?
спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создаем  переменные

```
x1 <- c(100,300,150) 
 y1 <- 450
```

результат

```
x1
[1] 100 300 150
 y1
[1] 450
```

нормализируем  `x1`

```
norm.x1 <- scale(x1,center = T,scale = T)
```

нормализируем `y1` в нормализированой области `х1`

```
norm.y1 <- scale(y1,center = mean(x1),scale = sd(x1))
```

результат

```
> as.vector(norm.x1)
[1] -0.8006408  1.1208971 -0.3202563
> as.vector(norm.y1)
[1] 2.56205
```

денормализируем переменные

```
denorm.x1 <- norm.x1 * sd(x1) + mean(x1)
denorm.y1 <- norm.y1 * sd(x1) + mean(x1)
```

результат

```
> as.vector(denorm.x1)
[1] 100 300 150
> as.vector(denorm.y1)
[1] 450
```